# How do I make a fur for my teddybear?

Tags: particles, hair

I want a fur like the picture below. How can you do this in Blender?
[image: fur]

Comment: this guy have a REALLY decent tutorials: [Fur tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EVj1fETtuN8)

Comment: I see you have a good answer to this question, but please keep in mind that questions should show that you have researched the problem before posting on [blender.se].  Please read [ask] and [tour].

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could easily do this with Blender's particle system

The key thing here is that the hair seems to be forming clusters or gathering to form small clumps of fur.
This effect can be achieved with the particle children and activating the *Clump* parameter. This will create this bunching effect.

1. Add a new particle system to your object
2. Check to use the modifier stack
3. Active the *Children* option
4. Use a high value for the *Clump* setting like in the `0.7` to `0.9`range

[image: Particle Clump]

5. Adjust the number of children to be enough so that the hair clumping effect is visible, but not too much that it looks like a solid spike
6. Increase the particle count to a higher value to look dense enough (how high will depend on the actual size of your object), and not too high as to hide the "clumpiness" of the children

[image: Higher particle count]

Answer (score -2):

With a particle system. In the particle properties select hair.

Also https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Tutorials/Simulation/Hair/Using_the_Particle_Mode

Comment: Thanks for the posts. This is not a regular forum, according to site rules [links to answers are not answers](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2382) if the link goes missing your answer becomes an empty shell without content. Answers should be substantial and stand on their own without relying on external data like links, videos or images. Instead of having users go through external links, either transcribe essential parts of the process here, linking the source, or posts these in the comments section instead.