# Most efficient way to create these hairs

Tags: materials, particles, hair

I am trying to make a pipe cleaner but I am having some trouble to create the hair strands on it. I also want the strands to be translucent from the top part to absorb some of the light.
The hair strands are bunched together and then the bunches are spread across the metal wire.
I have tried multiple particle systems and also tried to fake it with a mesh but nothing seems to be working since I require good detail. So what would be the most appropriate and efficient way for it?
Thanks.
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I make a fur for my teddybear?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58339/how-do-i-make-a-fur-for-my-teddybear)

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought, but could you model one bunch of strands with maybe a cluster of image planes, get that bunch to look correct, and then apply it as the render object for a particle hair system?

Comment: Also could try an array modifier if the particle system is not orderly enough.

Comment: hi Skyler Jyvqh, welcome to Blender SE! You can always [edit] your posts to add more information (instead of adding a comment). Check the [tour] and the [help] if you want to know more about the site.