# Replicating this fur from the new Animal Crossing?

Tags: materials, particles, hair

I am very interested in trying to replicate this short, fuzzy and soft fur from the  new Animal Crossing game. I am relatively new to 3D modeling, and don't quite know how to go about this. I was thinking perhaps really short curly hair, or maybe even a felt-like material?

Thank you for your time.

[image]

Comment: you can find how to do it with particles > Hair ( https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58339/how-do-i-make-a-fur-for-my-teddybear ) but I'd be curious to know if we can do without particles.