# How can I get a detailed fleece texture in blender

Tags: texturing, particles, geometry-nodes, procedural, photorealism

I have a 3D model of this jacket that I made with all the textures and stuff already. I have a fleece texture on it with displacement but it just doesn't look that realistic. I have to do a close up shot of the jacket So I need the texture to be good in detail. I think it might be possible through hair particles but I am having a hard time figuring it out, So It will mean alot if I can get some help.

[image]

Here is the image of the reference I used and how I want the fleece to look like.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58339/how-do-i-make-a-fur-for-my-teddybear

Comment: What kind of answer is this question actually aiming at? [tag:geometry-nodes], [tag:particles] or [tag:texturing]?