# How to make a Fleece texture for my cap model?

Tags: texturing, shaders, particles, displacement

I need help achieving a fleece texture for my cap model, I have tried procedural, image texture, particle system and even microdisplacement but can't still seem to get it right

What I achieved with particle system
[image: The fleece texture]

The fleece texture that I am trying to achieve
[image: The fleece texture]

I'll provide the texture that I'm trying to achieve and the result I am getting in the last 10-20 trials

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/279402/how-can-i-get-a-detailed-fleece-texture-in-blender https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58339/how-do-i-make-a-fur-for-my-teddybear