How to make a realistic boucle material?
I studied geometry nodes for a few days. Actually it was very easy, here is the result:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1X0YZoqVyWqt7sBbAFg85wSHSf1k4qmHg/view?usp=sharing

I am working on a project with bouclé material, but the bouclé material always looks very bad. I have tried BlenderKit and Poliigon, but it does not work, the result looks terrible.
Maybe I should use geometry nodes to create the bouclé material? I saw one that made a very nice bouclé material; perhaps someone knows how to do it? It looks like it was made with geometry nodes.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pYFM1r3spVU

Updates:
I tried geometry nodes cloth simulation to get the surface, here is the result, but it should be more
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bLvpsX1mgfM-flVTc_1-M8rnjpcrBP6G/view?usp=sharing



What object is it for? Could you share what you have as far?

Use particles? Or use a normal map to fake it?

@MartynasŽiemys it was a very basic sofa https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jFRGj3WREoEBItUa6-99Bqznq-kUowdw/view?usp=sharing

@moonboots i tryed a lot textures, norm, dislacement.....not work

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/279402/how-can-i-get-a-detailed-fleece-texture-in-blender https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/295787/how-to-make-a-fleece-texture-for-my-cap-model https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58339/how-do-i-make-a-fur-for-my-teddybear

@DuarteFarrajotaRamos Thanks for your answers. The seceond one is the material i try to acheive, i should study particle System maybe

One unusual way, I have used a few times to make this material is to offset a few layers of geometry(4-5) to form a few millimeter layer of sort of a volume approximation and then use noise texture(object texture coordinates so it's 3d) remapped to more appropriate range to make a volumetric mask. It requires 2 materials: 1 for the object and another for the "volume", but if sort of works OK for carpets and furniture sometimes. It seems to be easier and more efficient than displacement since you can have "volume" material slightly transparent/translucent and it's somewhat efficient in terms of resources:



It's not perfect when zoomed in too much, but it could work well in some situations. It works in the viewport(EEVEE) as well, but it sometimes looks different scale than in the render(Cycles), so it needs test renders. At least it used to in 4.0, not sure about 4.1.
The nodes for the "volume material":

I keep color variation from the image texture and add some sheen. I am sure one could make a more elaborate shader for it to look better, but that happens to be enough for me in this case.

thanks for the answer, but it is not what i really want

Why so? I was hoping this might work. What is it that you want? It could probably be possible to use geometry nodes to set it up procedurally and use one material separating the "volume" layers with an attribute.

it looks nice from afar, but if zoom in, the details are not fitting

Yeah, that's a good reason not to use it. Might be possible to push it a bit though. If you are doing displacement, and you have some forms that are relatively smooth and can normally be defined with less geometry it might still be efficient with more layers and it is should also be possible to change attributes of the noise per layer with geometry nodes so the clumps could be made to get smaller the closer they are to the outer surface, but that would be a fair bit of work with geometry nodes I guess.

I think with geometry nodes or partickel system zu rebuild the surfsce maybe the right may, because the surface changes so much because of boucle material

Personally I find particle systems not so practical for everyday kind of stuff. They take a lot of effort to make and require a lot of resources to render. Yes, a sofa alone might look good after a day of working with particles, but if you need it in an interior full of other stuff to fit into GPU memory and want to spend an hour on the material, I think this layered solution might be really great. This can be extremely efficient in terms of memory in some situations.

You are right, for interior it does not matt when die details are not so fit, but for sofa produkt there are views of details…..

i solved it, look the file on top

@MeiyingLu, please observe the rules of the platform. You must not  edit the title of the question if it's solved, but instead accept an answer that solved it or if there are no good answers, provide one yourself and post it as an answer.
